# Automation with Microsoft Test Manager and Selenium?

Tags: selenium, microsoft-test-manager

I was just given a project at work to look into feasible ways of implementing automatic tests.

I work for an ISP and for example, one test case would be testing the web interface of any given router.

I managed to record the button clicks with Selenium IDE and now I have the exported code base (Python in Visual Studio Code) of the test.

My question is as follows:

Can it somehow be implemented with Microsoft Test Manager 2017 (so that it passes the test if an expected thing happens)?

What would be the "easiest to grasp" framework to do something like this? I have little experience in coding but am willing to learn anything.

Can someone point me in the direction I should be looking to accomplish something like automated tests via Test Manager and a browser based automation software like Selenium IDE?

Much appreciated.
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft guides recommend associating MTM/TFS/Azure test cases via visual studio.
I also believe with the selenium IDE you can [export to c# and nunit](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/code-export)

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops) is the association guide.

Key bit is this:

[image: associating test cases]

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops) is the execution guide.

The trickiest bit about this approach is you'll need a visual studio license.